# Splay Tree Implementation

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, splay-tree

I am trying to implement a splay tree. But there is a segmentation fault occuring in the left_rotate and right_rotate function which is being called by splay() function. I have tried debugging but left with no clue. where am i doing wrong!
I think there is some kind of logical error.
Here is my code:

> splay_tree.h

```
 #include"node.h"
    
    template<class T>
    class splay_tree{
    private:
     Node<T>* root=nullptr;
    
    public:
       splay_tree(){
           root=nullptr;
       }
     //gethead
     Node<T>* gethead(){
         return this->root;
     }
      void left_rotate(Node<T>* node){
     if(node==nullptr){return ;}
     if(node->m_right!=nullptr){  
         Node<T>* temp= node->m_right;
      node->m_right= temp->m_left;
      if(temp->m_left){
          temp->m_left->m_parent=node;
      }
      temp->m_parent=node->m_parent;
      if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
          this->root=temp;
      }else if(node=node->m_parent->m_left){
            node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
      }else if(node=node->m_parent->m_right){
            node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
      }
      temp->m_left=node;
      node->m_parent=temp;
       }
      
 }
    //right rotate
     void right_rotate(Node<T>* node){
         Node<T>* temp= node->m_left;
         node->m_left=temp->m_right;
         if(temp->m_right){
             temp->m_right->m_parent=node;
         }
         temp->m_parent=node->m_parent;
         if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
             this->root=temp;
         }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
             node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
         }else{
             node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
         }
         temp->m_right=node;
         node->m_parent=temp;
         
     }
     //splaying the node
    void splay(Node<T>* node){
        while(node->m_parent){
            if(node->m_parent->m_parent==nullptr){
                if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right){
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }
            }else if(node->m_parent->m_parent!=nullptr){
                if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else{
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    void insert(T data){
        insert(data,this->root);
    }
    Node<T>* insert(T data,Node<T>* node){
        
        if(this->root==nullptr){
            this->root= new Node<T>(data);
            return this->root;
        }else{Node<T>* curr_ptr=node;
            while(node!=nullptr){
                
                if(data<node->m_data){
                    if(node->m_left!=nullptr){
                        node->m_left=insert(data,node->m_left);
                    }else{
                        Node<T>* new_node = new Node<T>(data);
                        curr_ptr->m_left= new_node;
                        new_node->m_parent=curr_ptr;
                        splay(new_node);
                    }
                    
                }else if(data> node->m_data){
                    if(node->m_right!= nullptr){
                        node->m_right= insert(data,node->m_right);
                    }else{
                        Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
                        curr_ptr->m_right= new_node;
                        new_node->m_parent=curr_ptr;
                        splay(new_node);
                    }
                    
                }
    
            }
       }
       return node;
    }
    };
```

> node.h

```
template<class T>

class Node{

  public:
        T m_data; // holds the key
    Node<T>* m_parent; // pointer to the parent
    Node<T>* m_left; // pointer to left child
    Node<T>* m_right; // pointer to right child
     Node(T data){
        m_data=data;
        m_left=nullptr ;
        m_right=nullptr ;
        m_parent=nullptr;
     }
     
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include"splay_tree.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     splay_tree<int> s1;
     cout<<s1.gethead();
      s1.insert(12);
      s1.insert(89);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the two functions you mentioned what if  Node<T>* temp= node->m_left;
     node->m_left=temp->m_right; node->m_left is itself nullptr! what are you assigning to a nullptr?

Comment: hi, can you tell us at which point the program fails? using printf()'s in the rotate functions should help you achieve that

Comment: here is the debugging message Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555557c4 in splay_tree<int>::left_rotate (this=0x7fffffffdbc0, node=0x55555556b2c0) at splay_tree.h:19
19                node->m_right= temp->m_left;

Comment: @Tushar tried that no changes occured.

Comment: are you sure the argument node is not nullptr? There should be a check for that in your code

Comment: @snus74 doesn' help same error t

Comment: and a check for node->m_right != nullptr. otherwise temp will be null and temp->m_left will cause a seg fault

Comment: @snus74 same error !

Comment: can you post the modified code as an edit please?

Comment: done please see @snus74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so here is what i found for your code

> You are using wrong nomenclature for the rotation functions i.e where it should be left_rotate you are using right_rotate.

Note: This may be because you are taking part of code from somewhere and other part from somewhere else. I strongly recommend you to try things on your own first.

Talking about the naming zig can be understood either as left or right so it may create confusion and that's what happened here!

For the answer part, I have updated names and improved your code !

```
void left_rotate(Node<T>* node){
     if(node==nullptr){return ;}
     else{
         Node<T>* temp= node->m_right;
         node->m_right=temp->m_left;
         if(temp->m_left){
             temp->m_left->m_parent=node;
         }
         temp->m_parent=node->m_parent;
         if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
             this->root=temp;
         }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
             node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
         }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
             node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
         }
         temp->m_left=node;
         node->m_parent=temp;
     }
    
 }
void right_rotate(Node<T>* node){
        Node<T>* temp=node->m_left;
        node->m_left=temp->m_right;
        if(temp->m_right){
            temp->m_right->m_parent=node;
        }
        temp->m_parent= node->m_parent;
        if(node->m_parent==nullptr){
            this->root=temp;
        }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){
            node->m_parent->m_left=temp;
        }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right){
            node->m_parent->m_right=temp;
        }
        temp->m_right=node;
        node->m_parent=temp;
   }

   //splay Function
      void splay(Node<T>* node){
        while(node->m_parent){
            if(!node->m_parent->m_parent){
                if(node==node->m_parent->m_left){//zig Rotation
                    right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_right){
                    left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                }
            }
            else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){//Zig Zig 
                right_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent==node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){//zag zag
                left_rotate(node->m_parent->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node==node->m_parent->m_left && node->m_parent== node->m_parent->m_parent->m_right){
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }else if(node== node->m_parent->m_right && node->m_parent== node->m_parent->m_parent->m_left){
                left_rotate(node->m_parent);
                right_rotate(node->m_parent);
            }
        }
      }



    //Insert Function
void insert(T data){
    Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
    Node<T>* y= nullptr;
    Node<T>* x= this->root;
    while (x!= nullptr){
        y=x;
        if(new_node->m_data<x->m_data){
            x= x->m_left;
        }
        else{
            x=x->m_right;
        }
    }
        // y is a m_parent of x
        new_node->m_parent=y;
        if(y==nullptr){
            this->root=new_node;
        }else if(new_node->m_data<y->m_data){
            y->m_left=new_node;
        }else{
            y->m_right=new_node;
        }
    
    splay(new_node);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking more carefully, there is definitely an issue with what you are doing.
Lets break the left_rotate code down with schematics:

This is what it looks like before you enter the rotate function

[image]

First instruction `Node<T>* temp = node->m_right` results in this:
This isn't wrong in itself but note that your new node temp is missing connections

[image]

Finally, `node->m_right = temp->m_left` would *in theory* look like that:

[image]

As you can see, `node->m_right` still has the incoming connections from the parents and the childs, and `temp->m_left` will point towards itself. This is what causes the segmentation fault.

What you *should* do to correct the error is:

1. Make sure you destroyed all the connections to node->m_right before assigning it to a new node.
2. Don't forget to add the connections **to** the new temp node

Comment: please see i too have a doubt